# Firebase: deleting documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this simple function which seems to output success that document has been deleted but I can see still the list of document on my Battles.

What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.removeOldBattles = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var coll = db.collection("Battles");
    coll.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            var battleId = doc.id;
            coll.doc(battleId).delete().then(function () {
                console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
                res.status(200).send("Document successfully deleted!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
                res.status(500).send(error);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is sending a response immediately after the first document is deleted.  It's not waiting to send a response after everything has been done.  Cloud Functions will terminate the function almost immediately after it sends the response (when you call `res.send()`), so it will likely not complete all the async work.

You should instead only send the response after **all** the documents are fully deleted.  This means you will have to pay attention to each of the promises returned by each call to `delete()`.  Collect them all into an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for them to all be fully complete before sending the response.

```
const promises = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    var battleId = doc.id;
    const promise = coll.doc(battleId).delete();
    promises.push(promise);
})
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send("Documents successfully deleted!");
});
```